# Add subcollection in cloud firestore using swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple problem. I have an existing document in cloud firestore and I simply want to add a subcollection to this document and add a document to this subcollection.

The following is my code for what I believe should do the job, but unfortunately doesn't. Also I dont get any errors.

```
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("users").document("John").collection("newSubcollection").addDocument(data: [
                        "age": 25
                    ]) { error in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error adding subcollection: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            print("subcollection added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                    }
```

The message I get is that it succesfully created the subcollection, but I dont see it. What is going wrong?

Comment: Check your database rules, if you have any. This code should work.

Comment: @KenMueller are there specific rules that allow creating subcollections or is it by default allowed? Also, the weird thing is that I do not get a security error in the console of Xcode when I do this.

Comment: @KenMueller my mistake, there is a security error indeed. But how do I allow creating subcollections?

Comment: Show me your rules and I can help!

Comment: @KenMueller I found out how to do it! I thought first that it would allow me implicitly if I did not have any rules, but it seems that I have to explicitly state that I have to be allowed to create documents in the subcollection

Comment: Great. Just as a reminder, Firestore rules don't pass down to subcollections. For example, if you have a document inside of a subcollection with read access, and another subcollection inside of that document, you have to create separate rules for that subdocument.